# Variable inside a bash heredoc

Tags: mysql, bash, heredoc

It looks like the variables is not getting populated eventhough in theory it should.
Am I missing something?

```
echo "Setting up: $db"

cat <<EOF > ./mysql_setup.sql
create database $db;
grant all on $db.* To $adm_user@localhost identified by '$adm_pass' WITH GRANT OPTION;
grant all on $db.* To $adm_user@'%' identified by '$adm_pass' WITH GRANT OPTION;

EOF

echo "quit" >> ./mysql_setup.sql
```

Comment: Where do you set `db`? And do you want `$adm_pass` to expand? If so, where do you set it? And what's in `msyql_setup.sql` after your commands, and what do you expect to be there?

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If I run the code you've put, none of the variables are defined.

Comment: Why do you put `quit` into the file with a separate `echo` command instead of putting that in the here-doc?

Comment: The code seems correct. Not sure what the problem could be.  It is working for me as-is _when I set the value of_ `db="TESTTESTTEST"` with `bash` v3.2 and v4.4 on OSX.

Comment: My apologies, the sabove code works. The issue was, I was modifying the $db varibale incorrectly, which is not in the question snippet.